# Backbone: passing data to server (save() method, php file)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, rest, backbone.js

Hope you can help me with that problem.

I want to use Backbone's save() method and pass to php file data.
But on a very begining I have problem.

In browser's console I execute:

```
var test = new MyModel(); //  - it's ok
test.toJSON(); // - it's ok
test.save(); // and here I have error "TypeError: d.collection is undefined"
```

When I use localStorage everythink is OK (it's commented in my code below). I can create models, collections, views etc. and operate on them.

I tried to use these tutorials net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/understanding-backbone-js-and-the-server/ and http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/restful-services-with-jquery-php-and-the-slim-framework/ but I can't get how REST works and where I made mistake. Hope you can explain.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>S.O.S</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Test</h1>
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="underscore-min.js"></script>
  <script src="backbone-min.js"></script>
  <script src="backbone.localStorage-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

<script >

  window.MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
      title: 'Test'
    },

    //localStorage: new Store('TEST')
    urlRoot: 'api/items'
  });


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

index.php

```
<?php
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
$app = new Slim();
$app->post('/items', 'addItem');
$app->run();


function addItem() {
    $request = Slim::getInstance()->request();
    try {
        echo json_encode('OK message'); 
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Error message'; 
    }
}
?>
```

folders structure

```
|->main_folder
           |-index.html
           |->api
                |->index.html
                |->Slim
                    |-> (folder with Slim php library)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/acDb3/
Even without working REST I didn't got the error you have.
I noticed there is no `Content-type` for JSON output. You may add this line to the `index.php` to make it work.

```
$app->contentType("application/json");
```

You can also get `success` and `error` callacks to see if they are have been called.

```
test.save(null, {
    success: function() {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```